# При повторной итерации пропускается gets(name[i])

Tags: c++, linux

Почему-то при вызове этой функции, при первой итерации все проходит нормально, но при второй итерации пропускается `gets(name[i])`, cледственно цикл прерывается. В чем проблема?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

char name[10][80];
char phone[10][20];
int hours[10];
int wage[10];

void enter();
void report();

int main()
{
    enter();
    report();

    return 0;
}

void enter()
{
    int i;
    cout << "Введите данные о работниках:" << endl;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << i << " работник:" << endl;
        cout << "Имя: ";
        gets(name[i]);
        if (!name[i][0])
            break;
        cout << "nТелефон: ";
        gets(phone[i]);
        cout << "nКоличество отработанных часов: ";
        cin >> hours[i];
        cout << "nОклад: ";
        cin >> wage[i];
        cout << 'n';
    }
```

Comment: Покажите весь код: как объявлены переменные `name`, `phone`, и пр.

Comment: Перенесено в вопрос.

Comment: Жуткая смесь С и С++. Бэээ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно пропускает.

Вы вводите *Оклад* (это целое) оператором `cin >>`, а он **оставляет символ `'\n'`** в stdin. Точнее он прочтет все цифры. А gets() в свою очередь читает поток **до `'\n'`, считывает его и не помещает в переменную**.

Вот это вы и читаете (точнее читаете пустую строку).

Просто добавьте gets() в конце цикла. Только вот еще, пожалуйста переделайте все с `gets` на `fgets()`.

Comment: а зачем с gets на fgets?

Comment: Лучше с gets на getline. И char[] на кошерный string.

Comment: учту ваш совет
но почему чар на стринг? вроде, насколько знаю, стринг медленнее обрабатывается

Answer (score 0):

Опытный хакер может хакнуть систему через вашу прогу путём переполнения буфера ввода (хитрое дело; я в подробности не вникал), а fgets() такого недопускает.

Т.е. с fgets() вместо gets() ваша прога потенциально более защищена.

[Почитать подробнее](http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1049157810&id=1043284351)

Comment: спасибо, но я ненастолько дружу с английским, чтобы прочитать)